# Django can no longer find base.html after third-pary API call

Tags: python, django, zoho

I am trying to make a call to a third-party API in my Django app, more specifically in a `views.py`. Once I make this call, Django fails to find the template `base.html`.

Essentially this is what's happening:

1. user searches for a term in a search form
2. the request gets sent to my view
3. the view has an if statement to handle when the user is making a GET request, so this piece of logic handles the request
4. the view makes a call to a separate function `search_by_jobsite()` written by me
5. inside `search_by_jobsite()`, a call to a third-party API is made, and I pass the location of a `.pkl` file to the API. The location is `/webapp/camera_search/api/pickle/config.pkl`.
6. Everything is fine and `search_by_jobsite()` retrieves the necessary information
7. It returns the information back to the view, and the view goes on to define the context dictionary and attempts to `render(request, 'siren_search.html', context)`. However, this is where it fails.

The first line in `siren_search.html` is `{% extends 'base.html' %}`, so it starts looking for `base.html` but it's looking in the wrong directory. It is searching for `base.html` in `/webapp/camera_search/api/pickle/` when `base.html` is located in `/webapp/webapp/templates/base.html`. For some reason when django goes to the `pickle/` folder to send the info to the third-party API, it starts searching for `base.html` there also, but it can find `siren_search.html` just find.

**Summary of what django is doing**:

1. Starts in `/webapp/camera_search/views.py` and makes third party API call
2. During API call, django moves to `/webapp/camera_search/api/pickle/`
3. Goes back to view `/webapp/camera_search/views.py`
4. Attempts to render `siren_search.html` and finds it in correct location `/webapp/camera_search/templates/siren_search.html`
5. Attempts to extend `base.html` and searches in `/webapp/camera_search/api/pickle/` but it's actually located in `/webapp/webapp/templates/base.html`.

Here is a link to the full traceback: http://dpaste.com/3ZTBJAG

My question is, what is going on and how do I re-route Django back to the proper directories?

**EDIT**:

Here is my TEMPLATES setting and my relevant code from `views.py`.

```py
# /webapp/webapp/settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['webapp/templates/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

```py
# /webapp/camera_search/views.py

from .models import CameraSystem, JobSite
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings
from zcrmsdk import ZCRMRecord, ZCRMRestClient, ZCRMModule

def siren_search(request):

    term = request.GET.get('query', '')
    context = {}

    #
    # ...
    #

    # Handle when the user presses enter
    elif 'query' in request.GET and term != '' and not request.is_ajax():
        try:
            deployed = search_by_jobsite('JOBSITE') # --- This is what i'm attempting to do. Currently the search works using the below functionality, but i'm trying to integrate this third party API call.
            jobsite = JobSite.objects.get(name__iexact=term)
            cameras = jobsite.camerasystem_set.all()
            context = {
                'cameras': cameras,
            }

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            context = {}
            pass

        return render(request, 'siren_search.html', context) # Django fails here

def search_by_jobsite(jobsite):
    # config is a dictionary with API authentication settings.
    config = settings.ZOHO_CONFIG 
    client = ZCRMRestClient.initialize(config)
    all_cameras = ZCRMModule.get_instance('Vendors').search_records(f'{jobsite}')
    deployed_cameras = {}

    # ... process data

    return deployed_cameras
```

Here is a sample config dictionary that I am passing to the API client.

```py
config = {
    'sandbox': 'False',
    'applicationLogFilePath': '/Users/user/Programming/suitee/webapp/camera_search/api/log/',
    'client_id': 'xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8000/',
    'accounts_url': 'https://accounts.zoho.com',
    'token_persistence_path': '/Users/user/Programming/suite/webapp/camera_search/api/pickle/',
    'currentUserEmail': 'email@domain.com'
}
```

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the API call. Please can you show your TEMPLATES setting plus the relevant view.

Comment: `DIRS` should probably be an absolute path, usually you would do `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webapp/templates')`; does that help?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes that works, thank you so much!